# This code didn't throw an exception or exit but runs infinitely why?

Tags: c

I was trying an experiment and I expected this code to throw an exception or print ambiguous value for n and exit but its end up running infinitely. Why it runs infinitely?

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {

    int y=5;
    int n=4;

    while(y || n) {
        printf("n = %d y = %d\n",n,y);

        y--;
        n--;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no exceptions in C. There may be a mechanism also called "exceptions" on the OS/hardware level, but these would occur only when you hit undefined behavior, which doesn't guarantee you any particular outcome in the first place. What exactly do you mean with "_print ambiguous value for n and exit_"? What is that expectation based on?

Comment: Yeah, until the underflow happens, there is nothing ambiguous about `n`; it's just a plain old integer decreasing by one on each iteration.

Comment: @user17732522 I was just trying to say unexpected value. Anyways I am new to c or any low level programming. I really appreciate you guys responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop runs as along a `y` OR `n` are non-zero.

For the loop to terminate, `y` and `n` would both have to be zero at the top of the loop, but that never happens because `y` and `n` start off not being equal to each other and each of them goes down by one each iteration.

Also note that signed integer overflow/underflow is *undefined behavior*, so if you run the loop long enough for that to happen, there are no guarantees about what will happen.